# How to use curl command to make a PUT request with api key and secret as authorisation method?

Tags: api, rest, curl, api-key

I want to execute an api call to a Saas platform. When I generate the api keys with my account in the platform then i get 2 things:-

1. api key id : `631f39f37564not/631f39f475646real/635c1192756key`
2. Secret key : `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ABCDE1234 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

I am executing the api with my following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

export FIELD=90

HOST=https://example.com

PUT_BODY="{\"value\":\"${FIELD}\",\"valueObjectType\":\"String\"}"
curl -sk -X PUT "${HOST}/api/v3/xyz/endpoint" \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H "referer: ${HOST}/" \
  -H "Authorization: apikey 631f39f37564not/631f39f475646real/635c1192756key" \
  -d"${PUT_BODY}" | jq '.'
```

I get 401 unauthorized error

{
"error": {
"status_code": 401,
"status": "Unauthorized"
}
}

Is `-H "Authorization: apikey 631f39f37564not/631f39f475646real/635c1192756key"` the correct way to specify the apikey or do i need to append secret also in the request?

Edit: I cannot use bearer token, need to use api key only.

Answer (score 0):

I converted your curl to PHP and changed the URL to my test site that response with the request header. Because you did not provide a link to the api documentation, I do not know if the request header is what they want. 
I find the output request header is the first step in trouble shooting curl requests.

This is what my test site received:

```
BODY=
${PUT_BODY}
BODY urlencoded
${PUT_BODY}
```

Your request headers:

```
Content-Length: 11
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: ${HOST}/
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

What is missing?  The authorization not included?

So let's try another way.

When the is a key and secret they are usually posted as post data in a POST request.

Yours is a PUT request?  No documentation.

When I tried your

```
"Authorization: apikey 631f39f37564not/631f39f475646real/635c1192756key"
```

curl ignored it and it was not in the request header.

Why the `application/json` content type header?
I would expect

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

And I would expect the key and secret to be posted as post data:

```
-d 'key=<key>&secret=<secret>'
```

But no documentation.

If it is supposed to be a PUT then the key and secret would be in the query string following the URL.

```
${HOST}/api/v3/xyz/endpoint?key=<key?&secret=<secret>"
```

Your api key does not look good.  Again no documentation.

The secret is even not in your request.  You say "need to use api key only".  
If that is true, why does the secret exist?